# Importing XML file for a partners product feed to my wordpress site

Tags: xml, database, import, affiliate

I am trying to upload a XML file to my wordpress site where i can show my clients products and get my site connected to the partner ads site so it can put a tracker on. I tried to upload the XML file via the important section at my wordpress dashboard but it gives me this error *"This does not appear to be a WXR file, missing/invalid WXR version number"*.

Any suggestions? :)

I tried to uploade the XML file but it gives me an error. I have my clients data which i need to put on my own wordpress site. My partners website is not an wordpress website though but a shopify website.

Comment: You may be failing a schema check.  A xml Data file is not WXR.  Try manually importing the xml (not as WXR).  See : https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050852091-Importing-and-exporting-a-WXR-file-in-WordPress#importing-in-the-dashboard